# HTML not linking to CSS

Tags: css, html

Just curious as to why this is not working:

HTML:
[image]

CSS:
[image]

But when I launch it in chrome, the HTML doesn't seem to be affected by the CSS. The text is black and hasn't been changed. Anyone Know how to fix?

Comment: directories are wrong. Your css is placed in a different folder but your current code refers to the same folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're in different directories:

```
C:\....\HTML FILES\firstHTMLfiles.html
C:\....\SCSS and CSS\firstCSSTest.css
```

your `<link>` tag is writen to assume that the .css file is in the SAME directory as the .html file.

Try

```
<link ... href="../SCSS and CSS/firstCSSTest.css" />
```

instead.

And generally speaking, **PICTURES** of "broken" code are useless here, since it forces us to re-type any relevant bits. But in this case, the code itself would have been useless, since your directory information wouldn't have been included. But next time... actual code please, not PICTURES of code.

Comment: This was the problem. I thought the CSS file didn't have to be in the same directory (Some one told me this...). I will accept your answer as a solution in 10 minutes. (There is a cool down of some sort)

Comment: it doesn't have to be, but your browser is not going to scan your entire system to try and find the file for you. you told it (essentially) "css is in the same dir" and it went looking there, and didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The title bars of the two windows show that the HTML and CSS files are in different directories, but the URL to the stylesheet in the HTML is a relative URL to a file in the *same* directory.

Either change the URL to point to the right directory or move the CSS file.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the same directory unless the URL says it is (which yours does).

Answer (score 0):

the html and css must be (with your code) in the same folder